# Line patterns with Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, kineticjs

Ok, so I'm trying to draw a line which takes a patterned image as its stroke instead of a solid color.  I know it's possible to fill a Rect or other shape with a pattern, but that's not what I'm trying to do, I'm working strictly with lines.  So my question is. Is it possible to pass an image into a pattern and use that pattern as a line's stroke?  Or should I just create a Rect and fill each one with my pattern?

```
var line = new Kinetic.Line({
points: [0, 0, 0, 500],
stroke: /Here's where I want the pattern to go\,
strokeWidth: strokeWidth
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html Canvas allows a pattern to be used to draw a stroke.

KineticJS does not allow a patterned stroke.

But you can use a Kinetic.Shape and grab a real html canvas context like this:

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hTP5J/

[image]

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context) {
    var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(320, 80);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(200, 100, 160, 170);
    ctx.closePath();
    var pattern=context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    ctx.strokeStyle=pattern;
    ctx.lineWidth=20;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  },
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.  I know the shape object is relatively new to Kinetic, maybe I should start using it more often.  Thanks again.

Comment: Would I be able to tween this?  For instance, I need to do this as a line, then expand the line with the pattern.

Comment: Yes.  This example uses fixed points.  You could replace the fixed points in the example with relative points--your lines triangle.x(),triangle.y(),triangle.strokeWidth(), etc).  Then you could tween those node values.

Comment: So something along the lines of:

`ctx.moveTo(100, 50);
triangle.x(100);
triangle.y(250);`

?  I'm not very familiar with Canvas, just started working with it recently.